# Parent element overriding child element style

Tags: css, sass

i would like to ask why is it whenever I add a style onto my `<a>` tag under my `header-navigation`. The child `<a>` tag inside `nav-bar-item` seems to be overridden to whatever was applied on the outer `<a>` tag. Shouldn't it supposed to only select the particular `<a>` tag?

Anyone able to figure out what was I doing wrong? Or there was thing I missed out while learning SCSS

HTML

```
<div class="header-navigation">
    <a href="#" style="font-size:2rem;">The Pot</a>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <li class="nav-bar-item">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-bar-item">
            <a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-bar-item">
            <a href="#">TESTIMONIAL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-bar-item">
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #454545;
    @include easeOut;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.header-navigation {
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    a {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        display: flex;
        align-self: flex-end;

        &-item {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 20px;

            &:hover {
                color: $primary-color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the selector "parent>child" (greater-than sign):

```
.header-navigation {
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    > a {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    }

    ...
```

You currently using the "parent child"-selector (space sign), that applies style to all following child- and child-child-elements of the parent.
See [`element>element`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) and [`element element`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp)

Comment: thank you sir that was the answer i was finding for. Guess i did not learn enough css to know there was such a selector. All i knew was basic css where > sign means all of the child.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving it a rule that all anchor links inside of `.header-navigation` need to be styled. Yet the child anchors are also part of `.header-navigation`. Therefore they will have that style unless you specify the style of anchors inside of `.nav-bar-item`

If you also add this:

```
.nav-bar-item a {
color: red;
}
```

Then the styles will only apply to the child anchors.